# Reading a value from 'this' instance in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I am printing 'this' instance in alert box, it is printing something like this.

```
[object Object]
```

But the actual content in it is

```
<dl>
   <dt>
       my Name <span> John Krishna </span>
   </dt>
   <dd>
       <span>My fathers name</span>
   </dd>
 </dl>
```

I want to display only 'my Name' instead of [object Object]. I mean what ever content of span in that 'dt' I want to display it in my alert box.

For this I tried out around in google, every where I am getting solutions like use child, or using inner html content and in some solutions someone written for loops. But I don't want to write any for loops around it which makes my code large.

Some one please suggest me some way that how can I print only "my Name" in alert box.

Comment: Please show some code to demonstrate.

Comment: `[object Object]` means that it's object and have some properties and/or methods. Can you tell us where is that 'this' object from?

Comment: where is the script that alerts the value

Comment: if you are just doing it for development try `console.log(object)`. If this is what you want for the end product, you have to use `innerhtml` or jquery `text`.

Comment: May I suggest a change to your markup? The usage of dl in this instance is incorrect IMO see http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/

Comment: Yaa exactly what you said is correct. Even I am using in the way how then explained in that link. But I haven't shown you other 'dt' and 'dd' content to avoid confusion while reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're trying to alert an entire object. You'll need to make use of [jQuery's `text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to display only the element's text.

If `this` is already selecting the `span` element you're after, you can simply use:

```js
alert($(this).text()); // Instead of alert($(this));
```

> I need only text inside 'dt' and content inside span should not be printed

For this we can use a regular expression to replace the `<span>` content from the `dt` element's HTML:

```js
alert($('dt').html().replace(/<span>.*<\/span>/,''));
```

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/NDgKb/) of this in use.

This is [96% faster](http://jsperf.com/clone-vs-replace) than using cloning the element as some of the other answers below have suggested.

Comment: If I use '($(this).text())' it will display complete text in that dl.
I need only text inside 'dt' and content inside span should not be printed.

Comment: @JohnKrishna I've updated my answer and given an example. :-)

Comment: Ya this is working really good.
Thank u very much James Donnelly.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you did the selection. If it is on the whole **dl** tag, than it should be something like this

```
alert($("dl").find("dt").clone().find("span").remove().end().html());
```

Where dl is an example selection. I don't know how you get it (by id, class etc.)

if you're selecting **dt** tag directly, than you should use a shorter version

```
alert($("dt").clone().find("span").remove().end().html());
```

Comment: 1 rep and you actually note the some of the things that matter above and beyond anyone else here - I think your answer isn't ideal, but still better groundwork - congrats, and welcome!

Comment: I wanted to thank a person on a response here, but I don't have enough reputation. It says I have to acquire 50. Thanks though, this is fastest idea I had.

Comment: @user2641433 there's no need to clone the element. You can just use a simple `replace()` on the HTML (as stated in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17990070/1317805)). Not sure why this answer received so many upvotes when all the other answers were downvoted.

Comment: @James Donnelly, I think you are right. Your version will be less memory consuming.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly All of the other answers are terrible (or at least started off that way); the fact that this worked for the OP notwithstanding, effort counts for something, too.

Comment: @GrantThomas of course, but this was really a two-part question. The main problem being that OP was initially alerting the entire object. The major fix being to change that to simply alert the text (or HTML) instead. An answer which points in the right direction is better than an answer which points in the wrong direction, and downvoting partly-correct answers will only confuse the OP into thinking that these answers are simply wrong more than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the span (e.g. `<span id="myname">Test Name</span>`) and then match on the id in jQuery (using `$("#myname")`) and alert the text of that element to return what you need.

For example:

```
alert($("myname").text());
```

Answer (score 0):

try to map  : collecting them into an array instead of two calls to $:

```
var texts = $('span').map(function(){
    return this.previousSibling.nodeValue
});
texts[0]; // "Some text followed by "
texts[1]; // " and another text followed by "
alert(texts[0]);
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score -1):

you will need to use:

```
$(this).html();
```

Comment: He only wants `my Name`, not all the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
alert($(this).find("dt span").text());
```

Getting the text outside of the span is a little tricky in jQuery. I found this code [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/):

```
var myName = $(this).find("dt")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

Comment: He wants 'my Name' as result, it's not inside the span.

Comment: @Epsilon That's the thing about the Q, broken English is hard to determine!

Comment: His question is confusing, because he also said _what ever content our of span in that 'dt'_

Comment: @Barmar Which, ultimately, makes no sense whatever, so hardly answerable.

Comment: I think he means 'out' instead of 'our'

Comment: I translated it to _I want to show the content of the <span> in the <dt>_. If we have to wait for the guy to become fluent in English before answering....

Comment: It will not print 'my Name', it will print 'John Krishna'.

Comment: @Barmar The fluent in English comment is extreme rhetoric - more that general assumptions are dangerous. And, based on the comment above, I'd hazard to say your assumption was wrong. Good job it wasn't anything important. (;

Answer (score -1):

```
try this:

     var name=$(this).children('dt').children('span').text();
     alert('name --->'+name);
```

Thanks